# denoise a rendered image

Tags: command-line, denoise

Is it possible to use the denoiser of blender on an already rendered image, considering it will be rendered using blender ?
(the reason being I'd like to use the resumable render via blender's command-line and once I think my image is precise enough use the denoiser on it)

(Edit 20 oct 2017)
The first versions of the denoiser was having such abilities, with the option "Keep denoising data"
https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Lukasstockner97/GSoC_2016/User_Documentation
It seams Luckas Stockner simplified it afterward to make the integration to the main branch easier.
Unfortunately, I can't find any build of that version :/

Comment: I don't think that you can do that, the denoiser works using the information on the tiles and render passes as they are created. To clean an image that has been already rendered you might want do do it in an image editing app like photos hop or Affinity Photo, or try one of the many sophisticated composting apps like Fusion or Natron.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. However doing the denoising "by hand" using photoshop would not be worth, regarding the lost of quality and the important time required. E.g., the denoising of blender doesn't blur textures.

Comment: Photoshop's despeckle tool should work well. Else re-enter in blender v2.79 using the denoiser option.

Comment: Maybe you can import the image as plane and render it again (!!), using denoiser? Not sure it would work...

Answer (score 1):

Blender’s compositor has despeckle and other filtering tools that you can use on imported images. In fact you can apply these across the frames of an entire animation sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It would be indeed simpler than using an external application. However that's not taking advantage of the denoising tool and information, which make it much easier and cleaner I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can absolutely do this using the Compositor as mentioned. It's not intuitive per say, but you import your image and reference it in the Compositor using the Node ref. Run it directly through the *Denoise node* and anything else you need. Then the non-intuitive part is that you render your scene, which will show you whatever is on stage, and then you'll see your image redone in the final window.

I use the *Output File* node to save it to the drive.

*Image Node > Denoise > Other adjustments if necessary > Output To File Node*

If you already have an entire image sequence rendered, you can actually import the image seq directly into the Compositor under the *Input Node* (make sure to select all the frames, it's not automatic), then feed that image source directly into your adjustments.

[image]